# Is it possible to perform a Restangular GET with multiple query parameters?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I've been attempting to perform a Restangular GET with multiple query parameters (for simple pagination) and it doesn't seem possible--at least with what I'm trying to do.  Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
Restangular.all('elevation').get({ pageParam: page, pageSizeParam: pageSize }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

WIth the expected response looking something like:

```
{ totalRecords: 233, elevations: {...} }
```

This does not work and results in the following:

> GET http://localhost:24287/elevation/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

I also attempting utilizing `customGET` as well which results in the same problem as above.

The only way I'm actually able to pass multiple query parameters is by using `getList`.  Unfortunately when utilizing the `getList` unsurprisingly the following error is thrown:

> Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else

To resolve this issue, the Restangular documentation states in the [My response is actually wrapped with some metadata. How do I get the data in that case?](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#my-response-is-actually-wrapped-with-some-metadata-how-do-i-get-the-data-in-that-case) section that I need to use `addResponseInterceptor` which I've done like so:

```
 RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
  var newResponse = [];
  if(response.data.totalRecords !== undefined) {
    newResponse.elevationData= {};
    newResponse.elevationData.totalRecords = response.data.totalRecords;
    newResponse.elevationData.elevations = response.data.elevations;
  }
  return newResponse;
});
```

After jumping through hoops this convoluted solution does in fact work.  Is there not an easier way to simply call Restangular's `get` with multiple query parameters and get an object returned?

At this point, it would be a magnitude easier to take Restangular out of the question and simply use the $http service like so:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:24287/elevation?page=' + page + '&pageSize=' + pageSize).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.data.totalRecords);
    console.log(result.data.elevations);
});
```

Though I really want to figure out a better way to do this with Restangular.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Does this help http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/restangular.html @ the button of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the link, though it looks like that covers basically the same this as the documentation with better examples :).

Comment: sorry buddy I tried... I stopped using restangular and started to use angulars native facilities because they seem to be better documented.

Comment: Agreed--I'm heading in that direction shortly myself.  It just seems to work easier.

Answer (score 1):

That's deadly simple, querying a ressource URL without an id, even with specific query params, and returning a single object is just not RESTful.

> Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else

It's precisely telling you the truth : your query could return an array, because you haven't specified a unique identifier (everything else is not unique).

> At this point, it would be a magnitude easier to take Restangular out of the question and simply use the $http service

Definately, since Restangular focuses on RESTful resource proxying, or you're gonna have to tweak it (interceptors, customGET, ...)

Comment: Cyril--I'm not returning just a single object, though, I am retrieveing a list, it's just wrapped in metadata (in this case total record count is a sibling to the list itself).  I am not querying for a unique ID because I'm looking for this list of all objects -- well, in this case, a subset of all of them -- a page.  My whole point is that there should be an easier way to pass multiple query parameters to any of the GET methods Restangular provides.

Comment: Slashp. And my whole point is that I don't think you can, because Restangular focuses on RESTful APIs. You followed the exact right path, and Restangular is so well designed that it guided you through the process: 1) you firstly tried to use `get`, being aware your API returns a single json object, and it dodn't let you add some parameters, because it's designed to return a single object by id and doesn't require any query. 2) you tried querying `getList`, it told you that your API should return a list, or the response need to be customized with an interceptor.

Comment: Not that simple, I should say, indeed. But there isn't any other solution if you do want to use Restangular. You're maybe right thinking you shouldn't since it doesn't seems to fit your purpose. See [RESTful](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)